Print protobuf with gdb
Hi I have used protobuf for many years yet never figured out a way to view them with gdb. Is this possible at all perhaps with a newer version of gdb and/or protobuf?  I'm using protobuf 3.10.1 and gdb 8.2-20 currently.
I have tried things in gdb like:
p protobufObject
<incomplete type>
p protobufObject.ShortDebugString()
<Couldn't find method....>
p protobufObject.ShortDebugString().c_str()
<Coudln't find method...>
p protobufObject.PrintDebugString()
<Couldn't find method...>

Is there a pretty print option or anything that can view the full message in gdb?  I am aware that I could print this information to console but I want to view it in gdb if at all possible.

Probably PrintDebugString: https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.message/#Message.PrintDebugString? Documentation says it is "Convenience function useful in GDB".

OK after messing with this a bit it does seem like gdb's pretty-printer works out of the box with protobuf.  At issue is that the protobuf library I was using was not generated with debugging information in it.  I rebuilt the library with:
gcc -g ...

Then re-ran:
p protobufObject

I was now able to see the protobuf information.  I was also then able to see the ShortDebugString string appear.
I was surprised that the ShortDebugString/PrintDebugString methods couldn't be invoked by gdb without the debugging symbols since I am using those methods in my code as well.  I guess I don't fully understand how gdb works but at least there is an answer for this now for the next person.
